Convert MSSQL image / varbinary column data to file
I have data from an (unknown) MSSQL server, in a column of type Image (I think this is an old variant of varbinary).
I want to make a script (preferably in Python or Typescript, but open for anything) that can take the data like the one in the gist below and spew out files.
I have attempted quite a few approaches, but been unable to convert the file in the gist below – the converted file becomes corrupted. I suppose that's due to my own encoding/converting-skill shortcomings.
https://gist.github.com/tomfa/2f9e63ee1cc3cd012ac4c9b1031de39f
My code
Below is my attempt at decoding the data with Python. The code runs fine, but the output PDF is not valid.
import binascii

s = open("data.dat").read()

# chop off the '0x' at the front.
s = s[2:]

# Decode hex to binary.
binary = binascii.unhexlify(s)

with open("test123.pdf", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(binary)


Please include your approach to see where you go wrong

"column of type Image (I think this is an old variant of varbinary)." image is a deprecated data type and has been since 2005. You should have long ago switched to varbinary(MAX) which replaced image.

HOw does the random link to GitHub relate here? If you want to include information include it in the question. The link isn't given with any context, and so irrelevant.

@ThomA Yes, it's deprecated a long time ago. I'm trying to extract data from an old database.
The Github gist is relevant because it includes example data that I'm unable to convert. It's ~200KB, should I include it inline here?

You can upload images to [so], yes. We also need to see your attempt(s); we can't explain why it isn't working if you don't know what those attempt(s) are.

@siggemannen Added an approach now that doesn't work for me. I also added the original PDF-file to the gist if that's useful.

You don't need to do neither # chop off the '0x' at the front nor binascii.unhexlify(s) the binary in sql server is just binary, no manipulations needed, just read it and write it. What you see when querying is usually a hexified version for the ladies, made to look readable. Also, why are you reading from file, not from sql server in your code

@siggemannen It seems to me that you're suggesting the Python code below? That would just recreate the file?
s = open("data.dat").read()

with open("test123.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(s)

I would be very grateful if you have any example code that works for the linked code, in any language.

But you don't read from the file in your "real code", but from sql server? Or am i missing something, or did you actually wrote data from sql server into a file and now want to read from the file?

@siggemannen I am up for anything. I have also written the code below to read from server, but I didn't include it as no one else can test/verify it them selves.
Here's that code if that's of interest: https://gist.github.com/tomfa/859a4ab265f159a86da6345eff045266

To answer your question @siggemannen: I just need to get an export of an old database. so my "real code" is just a one-off script. In other words don't care which language or method is used for converting the data.

It seems the Image field was zip'ed, and the data needed to be unzipped before it could be read.
from os import getenv
import pymssql
import zipfile

conn = pymssql.connect('server', 'user', 'password', 'database')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""
SELECT %s, %s FROM %s;
""" % ('filename_column', 'image_column', 'table'))

def unzip(archive):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(archive, 'r') as zip:
        for file in zip.namelist():
            zip.extract(member=file)

row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
    filename = row[1]
    imagedata = row[2]
    zip_path = f'./{filename}.zip'

    with open(zip_path, 'wb') as f:
        print("Writing %s" % filename)
        f.write(imagedata)

    unzip(zip_path)

    row = cursor.fetchone()

conn.close()


